# Laravel Mix 4.0.7 includes Vue

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I just upgraded our application to Laravel Mix 4.0.7 but now it seems to be having some issues regarding Vue.

I'm running a Laravel / React application with no Vue components whatsover, here's the problem I run into when running `npm run watch-poll`. Vue is not in my composer.json, package.json or in any JS files.

```
node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:244
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

The full backtrace is:

```
at updateCssLoader.rule (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Vue.js:39:26)
at Vue.updateCssLoader (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Vue.js:87:21)
at Vue.updateCssLoaders (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Vue.js:38:14)
at Vue.webpackConfig (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Vue.js:28:14)
at JavaScript.webpackConfig (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/JavaScript.js:87:18)
at Mix.listen.config (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:74:54)
at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Dispatcher.fire (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
at Mix.dispatch (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:119:25)
at WebpackConfig.build (node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:28:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:29:38)
at Module._compile (node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
at require (node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:133:13)
at requireConfig (node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:135:6)
at node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:142:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:140:15)
at yargs.parse (node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:241:39)
at Object.parse (node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
at node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:219:8
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:538:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:155:2)
```

There's nothing special about the webpack.config.js but here it is as well:

```
'use strict';

let mix                 = require('laravel-mix');
let ExtractTextPlugin   = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let LiveReloadPlugin    = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
let path                = require('path');

const backendExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/backend/app.min.css");

mix.react('resources/assets/backend/js/app.js', 'public/backend/js')
    .js('resources/assets/frontend/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/frontend/sass/app.scss', 'css/frontend.min.css')
    .webpackConfig({
       module: {
         "rules": [
           {
             "test": /\.css$/,
             "loader": backendExtract.extract({
                     "fallback": "style-loader",
                     "use": "css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:6]&minimize=true"
             })
           }
       ]
       },
       "plugins": [
            backendExtract,
            new LiveReloadPlugin()
        ]
    });
```

I've tried looking into the Laravel mix source but can't really determine what's making it trying to load any Vue components.

Comment: have you tried to remove preset `php artisan preset none` or even `php artisan preset react` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I've looked into it some more and I think the extract text webpack-plugin is causing issues with the current webpack version (4.27.1)

Comment: I;ve checked the dependencies, and the extract text plugin has webpack 3.11, but maybe it's not the main issue.